# Blogging with R: easy way to embed R in a blog post?

Tags: wordpress, r, blogs

There is [a very nice Mediawiki plugin for R](http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/index.php/R_Extension_for_MediaWiki) which allows you to embed R code in any wiki page.  It takes a little effort to configure, but it's really useful once you have it in place.

Does anyone know of an equivalent for embedding R in a blog post?  The only thing I could find was [this wordpress plugin called RWebFriend](http://lixiaoxu.lxxm.com/RwebFriend/), but it only allows you to send code to [Rweb](http://bayes.math.montana.edu/Rweb/).  I'm envisioning something where you can embed your code between two tags and it is executed and returned.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this. I looked for one for about 15 seconds then got distracted by some other shiny object and forgot to go back and look some more.

Answer (score 6):

I see that [there is a posting on this very subject on the "Learning R" blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/wordpress-blogging-with-r-in-3-steps/) today.  What a coincidence!

This uses Sweave to create the actual output, along with [a Python script called blogpost.py (from Stuart Rackham)](http://srackham.wordpress.com/blogpost-readme/) to upload the results onto the Wordpress blog.  I like that approach because using Sweave means that your blog output could easily be converted into a paper or a presentation ([with Beamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX))), so blogging becomes even more useful in the long run.

Comment: To get a pdf from asciidoc-file you would need to use a combination of asciidoc and dblatex. Actually asciidoc includes a nice wrapper script that makes it as easy as 'python a2x.py workflow_walkthrough.txt'

Answer (score 3):

You may have to integrate R into your blogging engine, not unlike the MediaWiki extension.

Or, going the other way, you take [**Rpad**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rpad) and wrap a blog engine around its web-based R interface.

Answer (score 3):

I see you asked this a year ago, and since there has been some updates since (relevant to WordPress blogs), I thought of referencing them.

I wrote two posts on the topic:

1. For wordpress.com hosted blogs:  [R syntax highlighting for bloggers on WordPress.com](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/09/r-syntax-highlighting-for-bloggers-on-wordpress-com/)
2. For wordpress.org self hosted blogs: [Highlight the R syntax on your (WordPress) blog using the wp-syntax plugin](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/r-syntax-highlight-on-your-blog-a-wordpress-plugin/)

p.s: I also published the talk I gave on useR2010 with other tips on [blogging about R](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/07/blogging-about-r-presentation-and-audio/), but the other the posts linked to are the ones answering your question.

Cheers, Tal

Comment: Thanks for the update, Tal.  It looks like these address syntax highlighting, but not interpretation.  I'm still looking forward to a wordpress plugin for R code parsing...

Comment: Thanks Shane.  Why do you think such a plugin would be more useful then simply syntax highlighting ?

Answer (score 3):

As of November 2014 there is easy method to blog from R to your blog hosted on github pages. No databases, no local environment, no new admin panels. Only web browser, github and R are required.

1. Fork [Jekyll Now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now) to deploy pre-configuerd [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) (a static site generator) into your github repo. Change new repo name.
2. Edit `_config.yml` to set some global variables (here you can setup RSS, Disqus, Google Analytics, etc.).
3. Your blog posts will be located in `_posts` directory.
4. Use R packages `rmarkdown` or `knitr` to render your `Rmd` file to `md`.
5. Upload/copy&paste your `YYYY-MM-DD-my-first_post.md` to `_posts` directory.

As example my minimalist blog at: [jangorecki.github.io](http://jangorecki.github.io/)
It's repo at [github.com/jangorecki/jangorecki.github.io](https://github.com/jangorecki/jangorecki.github.io)

Also storing `Rmd` files in your repo gives ability to reproduce the post (+R chunks of course) locally in R by anybody.

Answer (score 2):

There's a post on [Blogistic Reflections blog](http://blogisticreflections.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/welcome-to-blogistic-reflections/) how he is using Emacs/ESS org-mode to get the HTML export functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Most blogging software has an XML-RPC interface. So the easiest way to blog from R, could be by using this package: http://www.omegahat.org/XMLRPC/ and RCurl which can also be found on that site.

This would be by far the easiest way to go. If you google XML-RPC and Wordpress you can find code written for php, but it could help for writing the R code as well.

Answer (score 0):

For sweaving markdown to blogspot, a combination of the commandline tool Pandoc, R-package ascii and Python gdata module can be used. See [my blogpost](http://factbased.blogspot.com/2011/07/reproducible-blogging.html)